# libmx.dll is not found though exists in the PATH

Tags: c++, matlab, dll, visual-studio-2015

For some reason though I added to the PATH environmental variable while running the project, there's an error message that libmx.dll is missing

Comment: You don't give enough details about your setup. Assuming you talk about visual-studio,  you need to set it inside visual-studio, under project properties

Comment: If you changed the PATH variable in windows you will have to restart Visual Studio for the change to happen. A program's environment variables are not dynamic.

Comment: I restarted my PC... Still can't find it..

Comment: I added the path to the dll on the properties debugging, PATH= my_dll_dir;%PATH% and from some reason there was no error. It's strange because this directory exists in the %PATH% too..